# Align div left and right

Tags: html, css

In the codes below, I have two `<div>` tags. I want to align one `<div>` to the left and the other to the right, with the same height and width. Please help me to do this.

```
<div id="imgShow">
    <panel>
        <img class = "hidden" id="orginal" alt = "Goofy pic of me" runat="server" />
        <div id="ScrollImg" style="position:relative;width:900px; height:330px;overflow: scroll; top: 3px; left: -1px;left:auto">
            <canvas id = "drawing" height="1500" width="1200" >  
                <p>Canvas not supported</p>
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </panel>
</div>
<div id="divComplete" style="position:relative;width:100px; height:330px;overflow: scroll; top: 3px; right: -1px;right:auto"></div>
```

Comment: where is your css? which div u want in left and right?

Comment: @Era there is no css i did in html only

Comment: You are using `position:relative` for both divs, change them to `position:absolute` if you want them to positioned from `left:-1px` and `right:-1px` resp.

Comment: There are three div tags, so, which two you want to align?

Comment: @GauravRai ScrollImg and divcomplete div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/waqsw5ap/1/)**

```
<div id="imgShow" style="width:50%; height:330px;overflow: scroll;float:left;">
    <panel>
        <img class = "hidden" id="orginal" alt = "Goofy pic of me" runat="server" />
        <div id="ScrollImg">
            <canvas id = "drawing" height="1500" width="1200" >  
                <p>Canvas not supported</p>
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </panel>
</div>
<div id="divComplete" style="width:50%; height:330px;overflow: scroll;">Canvas not supported</div>
```

Comment: if i increase the width it moves divcomplete div moves down

Comment: here both div's have same width(50%)

Comment: I increased the both div to 100% bcoz 50 % is small then one div come down

Comment: it is not possible to sit two 100% div's side by side

Comment: Thanks For the answer

Answer (score 3):

Set the floats for each div with CSS: **[example](https://jsfiddle.net/u7m1obfz/)**

```
.left { width:50%; float:left; height:200px; background:red;}
.right { width:50%; float: right; height:200px; background: blue;}
```

Comment: Actually very nice solution +1 for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use floats:

```
<style>

#imgShow, #divComplete{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

</style>
```

If you want both at different widths, simply separate the css selectors and add the desired width.

PS: Avoid using inline CSS unless you need to, transfer these to a separate CSS file and include it in the `head` section

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitter bootstrap css for styling your divs. Simply add`class="col-xs-6"` to each div. Remember `class="col-xs-12"` is the full width that the div can take based on the width of the parent container. Using -xs- instead of -md- shrinks the div upon resize instead of knocking them down. If you want margins simply add change them to `col-xs-5`s then add a `col-xs-2` div in between. It's also good practice to use parent divs with `container-fluid` and `row` classes